# Remove underscore from list of enums?

Tags: c#

I'm using a enum with countries in a comboBox. All enums are in a class called Countries. Some of them has underscores like United_States_of_America. I need to remove those underscores before it shows in the comboBox?

My thought was to use `Replace("_", " ")`, simple if it was a common string, but not so simple with a combobox! Therefore I would preciate some help to solve this? Thanks!

```
private void InitializeGUI()
{
    // Fill comboBox with countries
    cmbCountries.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries))); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the power of Linq :)

```
private void InitializeGUI() 
{ 
    // Fill comboBox with countries 
    cmbCountries.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries))
                                    .Select(c => c.Replace("_", " "));  
}
```

Or using a foreach:

```
private void InitializeGUI() 
{ 
    // Fill comboBox with countries 
    string[] countryNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries));
    foreach (string countryName in countryNames)
    {
        cmbCountries.Items.Add(countryName.Replace("_", " "));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. It's better to "break" long lines, so the annoying scroll bar won't be here. Hope you're not mad, you can rollback if you want.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't been working with LINQ in my class, we are expected to use that in the next class. Could it be done in some other way? A little more basic?

Comment: Updated with example without LINQ

Comment: gdoron, could you please give me some more hints how to use foreach for this task?

Comment: Duncan, I get a red line when I use your code? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void InitializeGUI()
{
    // Fill comboBox with countries
    cmbCountries.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries))
        .Select(c => c.Replace("_", " "))); 
}
```

This will create an `IEnumerable<string>`, that contains the names you selected from `Enum` (well done, working with `Enum` always seems horribly to me) and then replaces the underscore for each name.

You could also write this as:

```
countryNames = from country
               in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries))
               select country.Replace("_", " ");
cmbCountries.Items.AddRange(countryNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Countries)).Select(x => x.Replace("_", " "));
```